# Do beam splitters work for very broad photons? (frequency bandwidth, spatial extent)

Tags: photons, quantum-optics

If I send a single photon through a usual beam splitter, is there a limit for the beam splitter to work properly related to the photons broadness in frequency or in space?

For example a femto second photon. It has a spatial extent of about $10^{-7}\,\text m$ but a very broad frequency bandwidth of about $10^{15}\,\text{Hz}$. Since there a so many different frequencies I am wondering if I can naively assume that the beam splitter works properly.

Maybe some expirienced experimenter can answer to that.

Answer (score 1):

There can be a pulse made up of many photons whose temporal length is a femtosecond, or there could be a single photo - one energy quantum, with a single wavelength.

So, if you know the spectral bandwidth of your short-pulse signal, compare that with the spectral transmittance of your beam splitter.  I'd suggest that unless you're right on the cutoff edge of a **very** sharp splitter, you will see essentially no variation in the transmittance over the spectral range of your pulse.

Edit: in response to garyp's comment, here's a spec for a commercial beamsplitter designed for ultrashort pulse systems (not "single photon") :

> Reflectivity   Rs = 50 ±5 %, 700–950 nm (UB.2)
>   Rs = 50 ±5 %, 680–1080 nm (UB.4)

See  https://www.newport.com/Beamsplitters-for-Ultrashort-Pulses/141167/1033/info.aspx#tab_Specifications  for full info.

I don't know what the 'state of the art' specs are, but Newport or LambdaPhysik or perhaps even Schott may have other short-pulse splitters available.

Comment: The OP asks about a femtosecond pulse.  The spectral range of such a pulse would cover most (if not all) of the entire visible band, wouldn't it?  Any real beamsplitter would distort the pulse.  Sharp cutoff not needed.

Comment: @garyp the OP's text says "single photon," which is a different situation.  But fair question (yours), so see my additional info.

Comment: I take strong issue with your first sentence. A state $|1,\omega⟩$ has a single photon at frequency $\omega$. The state $|\psi⟩=\int f(\omega)|1,\omega⟩\text d\omega$ also has definitely one photon, and can be as short as the inverse support of $f$. If a BS splits each $|1,\omega⟩$ photon equally, it will split $|\psi⟩$ in two as well. What is the operational difference between "a single photon with ill-defined frequency and a given duration" and "a superposition of states with one photon in all these single frequencies"?

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is that "having well-defined photon number $N=1$" and "being in an eigenstate of the field hamiltonian" are independent statements.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty  I plead guilty to providing engineering responses instead of quantum physics derivations.  A single photon will never be decomposed into two states by a splitter. It is observed later on in one channel or the other; further we can define a single photon's frequency to very high accuracy on the basis of our source (e.g. hyperfine electron level transition).  So, again from an engineering standpoint it makes little sense to discuss the temporal length of a single photon.

Comment: What I meant with a femto second photon is excactly the state $|\psi\rangle$ Emilio Pisanty wrote. And if one changes the word "split" into "superpose", I guess the record is set straight in his comment. @Witthoft: If you could delete the part "there is no femto second photon" I would set your answer to the accepted answer. And in addition: Do you know properties of the best commercial beam splitter for such a situation (very broad spectral width)?